# Firebase invalid key name although I've used correct ASCII signs

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, import, ascii

I want to import a json file containing three root nodes `accounts`, `conversations`, `groups`. When I import this file firebase gives me the error:

> Invalid JSON data or key values. Key values can’t contain $ # [ ] / or .

After trial and errors I've came to the conclusion that `conversations` as a key name returns invalid from firebase. I've tested to create all the nodes by themselves and imported the corresponding values, `accounts` and `groups` imports correctly but `conversations` still gives me the error. I've checked the ASCII signs and they are correct. I tried to import the whole json file in another project and it successfully imports with no errors. So this whole problem is kinda strange.

the json file looks like this:

```
{
  "accounts":{...},
  "conversations":{...},
  "groups":{...}
}
```

one sample of conversations:

```
{
"accounts": {
    "05BTRzXhLqMjVW3qc0ghBUWshZU2": {
        "age": "2005",
        "conversations": {
            "9GeTLIh4FnXZNl130bH3VJ4jVgx2": {
                "conversationId": "-LFUFQh-qNfhb-8ejxx_",
                "messagesRead": 2
            },
            "MwGQSVKpsINWyuFN4jqXtUe61gs2": {
                "conversationId": "-LFUFVc3KUzGeKB7ZTz_",
                "messagesRead": 6
            }
        },
        "description": "Hellå",
        "email": "julia_003@snaptive.se",
        "friends": ["9GeTLIh4FnXZNl130bHVgx2", "BoGkg201ncPzJNSsdanH63Rl1", "Jze43jVHCEeRmQtk3NwKpny1KxZ2", "KFFX4MLVdxQ0NVYPAqAXAbqUwzI2", "MwGQSVKpsINWyuFN4jqXtUe61gs2", "ShCHny6aAFTwjStKEjbHCEKPeKn2", "YMEk03V2wQdL0F6ksiUvD2ZQeS23", "iOWxILLPR6esVBlGp18YXIl2", "o3FUGu4iZrOWyXz3NfEB2e8zclj1", "sGhQzFEavLXOSM9LYRpVezhLMx72", "tM4W1z6onvSt6Zr28PdvrOzroAp1", "y2GF7WP1NQQ3X5hT5esYsHx8yj23"],
        "groups": {
            "-LFUFBE4wYiEETrdYYug": {
                "messagesRead": 1
            }
        },
        "img": "assets/images/profile.png",
        "introMeddelande": "0",
        "name": "Jullebulle",
        "provider": "Email",
        "pushToken": "ebL3o5QL73E:APAz4NMbCPOTmBbi1bGaLIyyIcxSSaRwvsR4YgGt2a7lHe5fsREuWKttPHvK0RSljaw0GH99ledEQwkM3HhfFCp9rPrCgEvM6q67X3CQRdoL11zpy1z2KTFdrZrD-BX1tI8C7g9eHaXmQt65j4Eow",
        "titel": "Elev",
        "userId": "05BTRzXhLqMjVW3qc0ghBUWshZU2",
        "username": "Julia_003"
    }
},
"conversations": {
    "-LA8fg4lUbLtGYBtR47Z": {
        "dateCreated": "Sun Apr 15 2018 16:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "messages": [{
            "avatar": "assets/images/profile.png",
            "date": "Sun Apr 15 2018 16:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "message": "Hej haris",
            "sender": "mJfUIr4eUccmtP1RhCGDH6UCr7W2",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "avatar": "assets/images/profile.png",
            "date": "Sun Apr 15 2018 16:21:47 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "sender": "mJfUIr4eUccmtP1RhCGDH6UCr7W2",
            "type": "image",
            "url": "link to firestore"
        }, {
            "date": "Sun Apr 15 2018 16:22:22 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "message": "Hej apple",
            "sender": "wIBBNjO8msR1zza8K6dYyTFdDWr1",
            "type": "text"
        }],
        "users": ["mJfUIr4eUccmtP1RhCGDH6UCr7W2", "wIBBNjO8msR1zza8K6dYyTFdDWr1"]
    }
},
"groups": {
    "-L3beONzO7Py_MhMBxuJ": {
        "dateCreated": "Wed Jan 24 2018 11:14:41 GMT+0100 (CET)",
        "description": "Jobb relaterat",
        "img": "assets/images/intern.jpg",
        "members": ["9GeTLIh4FnXZ0bH3VJ4jVgx2", "BoGkg2cEzJNSsdanH63Rl1", "Jze43jVHCEeRmQtk3NasdasdwKpny1KxZ2", "KFFX4MLVdxQ0NVYPAqAXAbqUwzI2", "KK6dLmN2UWgqWB90ixJCjEV2", "MwGQSVKpsINWyuFN4jqXt", "ShCHny6aAFTwjStKEjbHCE", "YMEk03V2wQdL0F6ksiUvD2ZQ", "iOWxILLPR6esVBlk5O7Gp18YXIl2", "o3FUGu4iZrOWyXz3NfEB2e8zclj1", "sGhQzFEavLXOSM9LYRpVezhLMx72", "tM4W1z6onvSt6Zr28PdvrOzroAp1", "y2GF7WP1NQQ3X5hT5esYsHx8yj23"],
        "messages": [{
            "date": "2018-04-16T16:39:08.000Z",
            "message": "Fresh",
            "sender": "wIBBNjO8msR1zza8KYyTFdDWr1",
            "type": "text"
        }, {
            "avatar": "lin to firestore",
            "date": "2018-04-17T04:56:13.000Z",
            "message": "Allt e redo nu",
            "sender": "o3FUGu4iWyXz3NfEB2e8zclj1",
            "smeknamn": "Cem Celepli Atci",
            "type": "text"
        }],
        "name": "Intern Chatt"
    }
}
}
```

the values look pretty much the same.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the minimal JSON file that exhibits the problem you describe.  Presumably you're importing through the Firebase console?

Comment: yes i am importing through the Firebase console.

Comment: and if I change "conversations" to something else like "test" the import works for some reason.

Comment: Please make sure the sample JSON is valid.  I want to be able to perform the import myself on actual data to exactly reproduce the issue that you're also seeing.

Comment: I have tested the whole json file in a jsonlint https://jsonlint.com/ and its valid.

Comment: I'm asking for a minimal sample that fails for you, so I can experience the problem for myself.

Comment: Sorry to be picky - that is a JSON fragment, not a full JSON file.  Please provide the complete, minimal file that causes an import error, and paste it here in its entirety.

Comment: its a pretty large file 4.4mb i cant post it here it contains ~90k lines

Comment: Right, so edit it down to the **minimal** file that reproduces the problem.  Without something exact to work with that everyone can agree fails, I don't see how you'll find a solution.

Comment: With this minimal sample the import works not with the full file though.

Comment: It sounds like you have some work to do to figure out where the offending key is located in there. :-(

Comment: any advice to find this offending key ?

Comment: Do it piece by piece, taking smaller portions of data each time you get the error. First try "Accounts", then "conversations", then a single conversation (if thats were the error is), and so on.

Comment: Okay so what should i look for? The forbidden ASCII signs ?

Comment: Buts its very strange because if I upload the json file to another Firebase project it works but if I upload it to my main project it fails.

Comment: now I can upload the file but only the first 5k lines of the file.

Comment: I can add the JSON you shared to a database without problems. See https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/51774736.json?print=pretty Without having a [minimal JSON that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be hard to help.